# Delay in the response of retrieving data from database give me null value

Tags: android

I declared variable "title" like this:

```
static String title;
```

This `title` should appear in the alert builder. When I display alert builder it gives me a null value (of the title) in the first time, but in the second time, it gives me true values.

I create a builder after implements two methods inside handleResult(Result result)

1. getAttName()
2. update()

Each of them should make a connection with a database (from different table and different PHP function). Also, I need to implement in this sequence 
how to solve this problem?

```
package com.example.lenovo.tactic4;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;



import android.content.Intent;

public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    String Attendee_ID;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    private static int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    int code;
    boolean updateFinish = false;
    public String eventID,subevent_ID;
    String attendeeName;
    private String URL_Scan_Update="http://192.168.1.5/phpApp/updateScanApp.php";
    String URL_AttendeeName= "http://192.168.1.5/phpApp/getAttNameApp.php?Attendee_ID=";
    static String title ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

        eventID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("eventID","");
        subevent_ID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("eventIdSubSelect","");
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);

        int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if(currentApiVersion >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if(checkPermission())
            {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission already granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission()
    {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void requestPermission()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                if(scannerView == null) {
                    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                    setContentView(scannerView);
                }
                scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                scannerView.startCamera();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted, Now you can access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied, You cannot access and camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA},
                                                            REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ScanActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        Attendee_ID = result.getText();
      //  Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
       // Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        getAttName();
        update(eventID,Attendee_ID,subevent_ID);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            finish();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, PrintActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("event_ID", eventID);
            intent.putExtra("Attendee_ID", Attendee_ID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
        builder.setMessage(title + "\n" + "do you want to print?");
    builder.create().show();


    }

    private void update( final String event_ID ,final String Attendee_ID ,final String subevent_ID) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_Scan_Update,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.d("Update: ",""+response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            if(jsonObject.getInt("value")==1){

                                 title = "welcome " +attendeeName +" login successful ";
                            }
                            else {

                                title = "welcome " +attendeeName +" you already login ";

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("event_ID", event_ID);
                params.put("Attendee_ID", Attendee_ID);
                params.put("subevent_ID", subevent_ID);

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);

    }
    private void getAttName(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_AttendeeName+Attendee_ID,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            attendeeName = jObj.getString("name");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if(error != null){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

        );

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `update()` inside `handleResult()`, you start a new asynchronous network call and on `onResponse()`, you update the title.
But the catch here is, the network call happens on a background thread and when the call finishes, then you get a `onResponse()` method callback in you activity.

To solve this,

1. you have to remove alert dialog calls from `handleResult()`
2. and call the alert dialog from inside the `onResponse()` method

**Edit:**

Example:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {

    getAttName(Result result);

}

private void getAttName(final Result result ){
    Attendee_ID = result.getText();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_AttendeeName+Attendee_ID,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        attendeeName = jObj.getString("name");
                        update(eventID,Attendee_ID,subevent_ID);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

    );

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

private void update( final String event_ID ,final String Attendee_ID ,final String subevent_ID) {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_Scan_Update,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("Update: ",""+response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        if(jsonObject.getInt("value")==1){

                             title = "welcome " +attendeeName +" login successful ";
                        }
                        else {

                            title = "welcome " +attendeeName +" you already login ";

                        }
                        showAlert();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("event_ID", event_ID);
            params.put("Attendee_ID", Attendee_ID);
            params.put("subevent_ID", subevent_ID);

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);

}

private void showAlert(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        finish();
    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, PrintActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("event_ID", eventID);
        intent.putExtra("Attendee_ID", Attendee_ID);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
    builder.setMessage(title + "\n" + "do you want to print?");
builder.create().show();
}
```

(there still might be simple bugs, like variable naming or access, try to solve them yourself as i don't have full code)

Comment: I am trying to make method  builderAlert(); it just have alert dialog and i call it after last line of update() method. it will be like this but still not work queue.add(postRequest);
builderAlert();

Comment: the point is, if a line comes after another line, naturally it is guaranteed to run after, if and only if, **they are on the same thread**....but here you are creating another thread, so, natural single threaded approach is not working...thats why you have to show to alert dialog `onRespone`, when the thread is done and gives callback to main thread

Comment: I understand that I should create another thread but I do not know how, although I watch many tutorial videos. can you give an example of how to implement this, please? or suggest a tutorial to watch.

Comment: I try to call update() in onRespons() of getAttName() and call alert dialog inside onRespons() of update. it works when I choose sub-event but when I choose just event did not implement the update()  (no enter to it)

Comment: i edited my post check now, accept if it solves the problem